# Using structs inside one another

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to define two structs inside a header file that both of them contain each other as objects. More specifically:

```
typedef struct Dweller {
    int id;
    int age;
    std::string name, lastname;

    Room room;

    float foodconsume;
    float waterconsume;
};

typedef struct Room {
    int id;

    int WIDTH = 400;
    int HEIGHT = 100;

    std::vector<Dweller> dwellers;
    float energyconsumed;
    int property;
    int floor, roomno;
};
```

But as you might have noticed, this is an issue because the `Dweller` doesn't know what `Room` is at that point of the code. I am using C++, and I am aware that I can make them classes, then forward declare them. But I want to know if I can achieve something like this without getting them into classes. I also want to use them seperately, so I don't want one of them getting declared inside other one.

Comment: If this code would work, these structs would be infinite in size. Which may require a significant RAM upgrade.

Comment: Hmm, could you explain why?

Comment: Because `Dweller` contains a `Room`, and a `Room` contains an unlimited amount of `Dweller`s? There's also a little problem that `Dweller dwellers[];` is not valid C++. But, whatever the size of this array is, you have both classes containing each other. That's the reason for the serious RAM upgrade.

Comment: @guacamolest Because you have a circular reference. The room has dwellers and the dwellers themselves have a room associated. You need only one of these.

Comment: P.S.: whichever C++ textbook youi're using that gives an example of `"typedef struct"`-something: you should replace it with a better C++ textbook. You only need to do something like that in C, but not C++.

Comment: I think what you want to do is to change the two classes to contain *pointers* to each other.

Comment: Can i not make something similar to forward declaring in structs? Also, yeah that's a mistake on my part that the dwellers class doesn't have an initial size.

Comment: A forward declaration won't help you when class A contains B, and class B contains A. This will require an infinite amount of RAM. And there is no such thing as an "initial size" of arrays in C++. In C++ all arrays have a fixed size.

Comment: I know that arrays have fixed size, I wanted to say that... Anyways, I think I understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things:

1. As Sam said, get rid of the `typedef`s.
2. Change the declaration `Room room` in Dweller to `Room* room` and vice versa.
3. To satisfy the compiler, put two forward declarations up front:

   ```cpp
   struct Dweller;
   struct Room;
   ```